# Rails form_for radio_button "Can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have the following code:

```
<% form_for(@libation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :carbonated, true  %> <%= f.label :carbonated, "Yes" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :carbonated, false %> <%= f.label :carbonated,  "No" %>
<% end %>
```

The `carbonated` column in the database is of type `tinyint`.
And when the above is run and I click `No` I get a big red box telling me:

```
1 error prohibited this libation from being saved
  There were problems with the following fields:
  * Carbonated can't be blank
```

Any ideas?
-thanx

Answer (score 16):

I had difficulties with the validation of a boolean value, so i learned to validate their presence you need to do:

```
validates_inclusion_of :carbonated, :in => [true, false]
```

Answer (score -5):

Hah, answering my own question. Seems there is a problem with HTML spec not sending a "false" properly, so need some work around. For me, in the model file I had:

```
validates_presence_of :carbonated
```

and simply removing it fixes this error message. I default to false and it can be changed to true. Error message gone.

ciao.